# Passing a string to a bash script via an argument

Tags: git, bash

I'm writing a bash script that, amongst other things, triggers a git commit on a codebase for a specified Drupal 6 site. The script accepts two arguments, the second of which is the commit message for the git commit.

```
#!/bin/sh

directoryName=${1}
commitMsg=${2}

echo $directoryName
echo $commitMsg

git add .
git commit -vam "The commit message"
```

The script is called like this:

```
sh git-bash-test.sh name_of_directory "Custom commit message"
```

How can I change out "The commit message" for the value stored in $commitMsg?

Comment: The answer seems too obvious to be what you're really asking; "git commit -vam "${commitMsg}""? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply replace it with "$commitMsg":

git commit -vam "$commitMsg"

Answer (score 1):

```
sh git-bash-test.sh name_of_directory "$commitMsg"
```

Note the double-quotes around `$commitMsg`.